# デジタル時計は動いていないのに、更新される奇妙な現象

Tags: javascript

下記のコードは、1分おきに"和暦"と"西暦"に切り替わる『(カレンダー機能付き)デジタル時計』で、
マウスポインターにくっついて来るものです。
しかし、問題があるのです。
デジタル時計は、一分ごとに更新されるのに秒針が動いていないのです。
このデジタル時計を動いている状態にするには、どうすればいいでしょうか。

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="ja">
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Script-Type" content="text/javascript">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Style-Type" content="text/css">
    <title>文字マウスストーカー</title>


    <style type="text/css">

    #myText {
    font-style: italic;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: 'comic sans ms', verdana, arial;
    color: gold;

    position: absolute;top: 0;left: 0;z-index: 3000;cursor: default;}
    #myText div {position: relative;}
    #myText div div {position: absolute;top: 0;left: 0;text-align: center;}

    </style>


    <script type="text/javascript">
    <!--
/* Circling text trail- Tim Tilton
 Website: http://www.tempermedia.com/
 Visit: http://www.dynamicdrive.com/ for Original Source and tons of scripts
 Modified Here for more flexibility and modern browser support
 Modifications as first seen in http://www.dynamicdrive.com/forums/
 username:jscheuer1 - This notice must remain for legal use
 */



    ;(function(){

    var msg =  "";


    var size = 24;

    var circleY = 0.75; var circleX = 2;

    var letter_spacing = 5;

    var diameter = 10;

    var rotation = 0.4;
    var speed = 0.3;

    if (!window.addEventListener && !window.attachEvent || !document.createElement) return;

    msg = msg.split('');
    var n = msg.length - 1, a = Math.round(size * diameter * 0.208333), currStep = 20,
    ymouse = a * circleY + 20, xmouse = a * circleX + 20, y = [], x = [], Y = [], X = [],
    o = document.createElement('div'), oi = document.createElement('div'),
    b = document.compatMode && document.compatMode != "BackCompat"? document.documentElement : document.body,

    mouse = function(e){
     e = e || window.event;
     ymouse = !isNaN(e.pageY)? e.pageY : e.clientY; // y-position
     xmouse = !isNaN(e.pageX)? e.pageX : e.clientX; // x-position
    },

    makecircle = function(){ // rotation/positioning

     if(init.nopy){
      o.style.top = (b || document.body).scrollTop + 'px';
      o.style.left = (b || document.body).scrollLeft + 'px';
     };
     currStep -= rotation;
     for (var d, i = n; i > -1; --i){ // makes the circle
      d = document.getElementById('iemsg' + i).style;
      d.top = Math.round(y[i] + a * Math.sin((currStep + i) / letter_spacing) * circleY - 15) + 'px';
      d.left = Math.round(x[i] + a * Math.cos((currStep + i) / letter_spacing) * circleX) + 'px';
     };
    }

    var tMsg = ' ';
    var lastTLocale = '';

    function digi(Hour,Min,Sec){

      var t = tMsg;

      var date = new Date();
      var mt = date.getMinutes();

       if( mt%2==0 ){

          if(lastTLocale!= 'info1'){

              var time = new Date(),

                  m = new Array("１月", "２月", "３月", "４月", "５月", "６月", "７月", "８月", "９月", "10月", "11月", "12月"),
                  w = new Array("㊐", "㊊", "㊋", "㊌", "㊍", "㊎", "㊏"),

                 month = m[time.getMonth()],
                 day = time.getDate(),
                 week = w[time.getDay()];

               t =  "◆" + " " + month + day + "日" + " " + week + " " + "★" + "★" + " " + time.toLocaleDateString("ja-JP-u-ca-japanese", { era: "long", year: "numeric" }).replace(/\u200e/g, "").replace(" ", "").replace(/(^|[^\d])1(?=$|[^\d])/, '$1元') + " " +  "◆" + Hour + ":" + Min + ":" + Sec;
              lastTLocale = 'info1';
        }
    }

    else{

          if(lastTLocale != 'info2'){

             var time = new Date(),
                  w = ["Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat"],
                  m = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"],

                 week = w[time.getDay()],
                 month = m[time.getMonth()],
                 day = time.getDate(),
                 year = time.getYear() + 1900;

                    if ((day == 1 ) || (day == 21 ) || (day == 31 )) {
                        day = day + "st";
                    }
                    else if ((day == 2 ) || (day == 22 )) {
                        day = day + "nd";
                    }
                    else if ((day == 3 ) || (day == 23 )) {
                        day = day + "rd";
                    }
                    else {
                        day = day + "th";
                    }

                t = "★" + " " + week + " " + day + " " + month + " " + year + " "+ Hour + ":" + Min + ":" + Sec + "★";
                lastTLocale = 'info2';

       }
    }
        var currentLength = msg.length;

      if (t != tMsg) {
        tMsg=t;

        // 状態の変更
        msg = t.split('');
        n = msg.length - 1;

        // 文字要素の変更
        for (var i = Math.max(currentLength, msg.length) - 1; i > -1; --i)
        {
            var d = i < currentLength ? document.getElementById('iemsg' + i) : null;
            if (d)
            {
                if (i < t.length)
                {
                    // 既存要素の内容変更
                    d.innerHTML = msg[i];
                }
                else
                {
                    // 不要になった要素の削除
                    d.parentElement.removeChild(d);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                // 不足要素の追加
                d = document.createElement('div');
                d.id = 'iemsg' + i;
                d.style.height = d.style.width = a + 'px';
                d.appendChild(document.createTextNode(msg[i]));
                oi.appendChild(d); y[i] = x[i] = Y[i] = X[i] = 0;
            }
        }
    };

    ascroll = function(){

     ymouse += window.pageYOffset;
     xmouse += window.pageXOffset;
     window.removeEventListener('scroll', ascroll, false);
    };

    o.id = 'myText'; o.style.fontSize = size + 'px';
    }

    function drag(){
     var time = new Date(),
         Hour = time.getHours(),
         Min = time.getMinutes(),
         Sec = time.getSeconds();

            if(Min <= 9) { 
                           Min = "0" + Min; 
    }
            if(Sec <= 9) { 
                           Sec = "0" + Sec; 
    }

     y[0] = Y[0] += (ymouse - Y[0]) * speed;
     x[0] = X[0] += (xmouse - 20 - X[0]) * speed;
     for (var i = n; i > 0; --i){
      y[i] = Y[i] += (y[i-1] - Y[i]) * speed;
      x[i] = X[i] += (x[i-1] - X[i]) * speed;
     };
     makecircle();digi(Hour,Min,Sec);
    }

    function init(){
     if(!isNaN(window.pageYOffset)){
      ymouse += window.pageYOffset;
      xmouse += window.pageXOffset;
     } else init.nopy = true;
     for (var d, i = n; i > -1; --i){
      d = document.createElement('div'); d.id = 'iemsg' + i;
      d.style.height = d.style.width = a + 'px';
      d.appendChild(document.createTextNode(msg[i]));
      oi.appendChild(d); y[i] = x[i] = Y[i] = X[i] = 0;
     };
     o.appendChild(oi); document.body.appendChild(o);
     setInterval(drag, 25);
    }

    if (window.addEventListener){

     window.addEventListener('load', init, false);
     document.addEventListener('mouseover', mouse, false);
     document.addEventListener('mousemove', mouse, false);
      if (/Apple/.test(navigator.vendor))
       window.addEventListener('scroll', ascroll, false);
    }
    else if (window.attachEvent){
     window.attachEvent('onload', init);
     document.attachEvent('onmousemove', mouse);
    }
    })();
    // -->
    </script>

    </head>

    <body bgcolor="black">

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: 問題を再現するのに不要な部分は事前に削ぎ落とせないでしょうか(例えば今回なら「和暦と西暦が切り替わる部分」など)。質問と回答に集中するためにも、コード全体をそのまま貼り付けるのは避けてください。

Comment: 不要な部分(月日，曜日)はありそうですが、このコードでは切り換えなければ更新できないようですので、その部分は削れません。デジタル時計を動かすことはできますが、このコードでは苦闘しています。

Comment: [良い質問をするには?](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) や [技術系メーリングリストで質問するときのパターン・ランゲージ](http://www.hyuki.com/writing/techask.html) を参考にしてください。コード全体の修正を求めるのは開発要求・デバッグ要求でしかありません。であればここに限らずＱ＆Ａサイトで回答を募るのではなく、開発者を雇うべきです。

Comment: @user28531 細々と申し訳ないですがもう何点か。1つ目、過去質問と関連があるなら、そうと分かるよう本文にリンクや一言を添えてもらうと、質問を見た人に対してより親切です。2つ目、コードが第三者が書いたものを参考にしているなら、これも出来れば分かるように一言添えましょう。コピーライトの問題もそうですが、あなたがコードの仕様を理解しているのか/いないのかにも関わってきます。これまでの流れを見ていると『動いていた他人のコードに手を加えたら思うように動かないので直して』と依頼しているだけのような印象を与えます。

Comment: デバッグの方法を学んだ方が良いのでは、と思います。他人に問題点を説明して解決してもらうだけではデバッグ能力は身につかないので、今後も同じことの繰り返しになるだけです。

Answer (score 1):

和暦を使い回して、デジタル時計を動かすのですから、digi関数内を下記のように書き直して
解決しました。

```
        var tMsg = ' ';
        var lastTLocale = '';

        function digi(Hour,Min,Sec){

      var t = tMsg;

      var t1=Hour + ":" + Min + ":" + Sec ;

          var date = new Date();
          var mt = date.getMinutes();

           if( mt%2==0 ){

              if(lastTLocale!= 'info1'){

                  var time = new Date(),

                      m = new Array("１月", "２月", "３月", "４月", "５月", "６月", "７月", "８月", "９月", "10月", "11月", "12月"),
                      w = new Array("㊐", "㊊", "㊋", "㊌", "㊍", "㊎", "㊏"),

                     month = m[time.getMonth()],
                     day = time.getDate(),
                     week = w[time.getDay()];

           tA =  "◆" + " " +  time.toLocaleDateString("ja-JP-u-ca-japanese", { era: "long", year: "numeric" }).replace(/\u200e/g, "").replace(" ", "").replace(/(^|[^\d])1(?=$|[^\d])/, '$1元') + month + day + "日" + " " + week + " " + "★" + "★" + " " + "◆";
          lastTLocale = 'info1';
    }
           t = tA + " " + t1;
}

        else{

              if(lastTLocale != 'info2'){

                 var time = new Date(),
                      w = ["Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat"],
                      m = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"],

                     week = w[time.getDay()],
                     month = m[time.getMonth()],
                     day = time.getDate(),
                     year = time.getYear() + 1900;

                        if ((day == 1 ) || (day == 21 ) || (day == 31 )) {
                            day = day + "st";
                        }
                        else if ((day == 2 ) || (day == 22 )) {
                            day = day + "nd";
                        }
                        else if ((day == 3 ) || (day == 23 )) {
                            day = day + "rd";
                        }
                        else {
                            day = day + "th";
                        }


                    tB = "★" + " " + week + " " + day + " " + month + " " + year;
                    lastTLocale = 'info2';
           }
                    t=tB+" "+  t1;
        }

～～～略
```